# Saving multiple files in excel through vba causes issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that does the following:
Open a template file
Copy the relevant information in that file
Save the file as Uniquekey_templatefile.xlsm

I have a loop created a loop which does this activity for 100s of Unique key / TempId. Basically creating and saving different files for each unique key.

The code works perfectly fine but after saving 10-15 files, looks like the code stops after generating few files.

```
Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filepath & TemplID & "_Template.xlsm"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

There is no loss of data as well. When I click on cancel, it moves to saving next file.

So all I need is an improvement to my code, that will click cancel if this message doesn't go after 15 seconds.

Comment: You don't re-calculate `TemplID`, so you're constantly overwriting the same file, are you aware of that?

Comment: Have you tried using `DoEvents` after `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?